# vuex unknown action type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, craftcms

Im having to use craft on a project, I have used Vue.js on the front end but cant get the VUEX store to fire actions:

My Vue store file is as follows:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import bookingFunnel from "../store/booking-funnel/index";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store =  new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    bookingFunnel
  }
});

export default store;
```

With the import looking as such:

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    language: 'lang',
    visible: true,
    vehicleId: null,
    quote: null
  },
  getters: {
    getLanguage(state) {
      return state.language;
    },
    getVisible(state) {
      return state.visible;
    },
    getApiUrl(state) {
      return state.apiUrl;
    },
    getVehicleId(state) {
      return state.vehicleId;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    toggle(state, payload) {
      state.visible = payload
    },
    setVehicleId(state, payload) {
      state.vehicleId = payload;
    },
    updateQuote(state, payload) {
      state.quote = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    toggleVisible(state) {
      state.commit('toggle', !state.state.visible);
    },
    updateVehicleId(state, payload) {
      state.vehicle_id = payload;
    }
  },
};
```

And my import as follows:

```
import store from "../vuejs/store/index";

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  delimiters: ["${", "}"],
  store,
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      toggleVisible: 'bookingFunnel/toggleVisible',
      updateVehicleId: 'bookingFunnel/updateVehicleId'
    }),
  },
});
```

To which I get the following error when i run:

```
this.$store.dispatch('updateVehicleId', id)
```

[vuex] unknown action type: updateVehicleId

Comment: updated ```namespaced: true,``` to false which removes the error but the store is not updating

Comment: As you're importing the action you can just use this.updateVehicleId(id)

Comment: Where are you runing ```this.$store.dispatch('updateVehicleId', id)```?

Comment: In a mixin file thats pulled in to a component

Answer (score 0):

I have built several projects with Vue 2 and Vuex, but haven't done a lot with modules.  However, I was able to build an example based on a pared down version of your code using the Vue CLI, and it works.  I did take 'mapActions' out of the loop to simplify the example.  You can add it back in.

booking-funnel.js

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    vehicleId: null,
  },
  getters: {
    getVehicleId(state) {
      return state.vehicleId;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setVehicleId(state, payload) {
      state.vehicleId = payload;
      console.log(state.vehicleId);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    updateVehicleId(context, payload) {
      context.commit('setVehicleId', payload)
    }
  },
};
```

store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import bookingFunnel from "../module/booking-funnel.js";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store =  new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    bookingFunnel
  }
});

export default store;
```

VueModuleAction.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Vuex Module Action</h3>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="updateId">Update Vehicle ID</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    updateId() {
      this.$store.dispatch('bookingFunnel/updateVehicleId', 2);
    },
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.$store.getters['bookingFunnel/getVehicleId']);
  }
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <vuex-module-action />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VuexModuleAction from '@/components/stackoverflow/vuex-module-action/VuexModuleAction'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      VuexModuleAction
    },
  }
</script>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import store from '@/components/stackoverflow/vuex-module-action/store'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is not 100% the same but I got the `same error message` so I guess somme people in my situation would end here.
It was due to module naming with namespacing enabled.

But in my case the module variable `userModule` has not the same name as the module namespace `user`.

I had to do:

```js
const Store = createStore({
  modules: {
    'user': userModule,
    'thing': thingModule,
  },
  ...
})
```

Did you try?

```js
const store =  new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    bookingFunnel: bookingFunnel
  }
});
```